# Animating the UINavigationBar from a solid colour to a transparent colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, transition-coordinator

I am trying to animate the navigation bar of this app from a solid colour to a transparent colour during a transition.

The `barStyle` and `translucent` properties also change for the new view controller.

The reason I do this is because we use a transparent nav bar and fade it in during scrolling...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat maxY = self.headerHeight - 64;

    CGFloat percentage = MIN(0.996, MAX(0, [self alphaFromPercentageWithEasing:offsetY / maxY]));

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIColor imageFromColor:self.themeColor alpha:percentage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

This works fine when scrolling but in order to get a transparent navigation bar you have to use the `backgroundImage` property of the `navigationBar`. If you try to use a colour with `alpha` less than 1 then the colour is used with alpha of 1. So you can't just use a transparent colour.

The problem I have is that during the transition I have the `transitionCoordinator` doing this...

```
[self.transitionCoordinator
 animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.themeColor;
 }
 completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
     // this is so that when popping back to here the bar alpha
     // is set correctly from the current scroll position
     [self scrollViewDidScroll:self.tableView];
 }];
```

Obviously, this will animate the colour from the original colour to the view controller's `themeColor` property with 100% alpha and then when the transition finishes the `navigationBar` just disappears.

I have even tried animating between images...

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIColor imageFromColor:originalColor alpha:1.0] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.transitionCoordinator
 animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIColor imageFromColor:self.themeColor alpha:0] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 }
 completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
     // this is so that when popping back to here the bar alpha
     // is set correctly from the current scroll position
     [self scrollViewDidScroll:self.tableView];
 }];
```

but this just sets it to the final image with 0% alpha without animation.

I'm looking for a way to animate from 100% alpha of the original colour to 0% alpha of the `themeColor` during the transition. So the bar will animate both from (for example) blue to red and 1.0 alpha to 0.0 alpha.

Is this even possible? Anyone know how?

Comment: Have you ever done this?

Comment: @MihaiFratu hey, I don't think I ever managed to get this working. Sorry